# Hausdorff and IoU are stopped changing while dice metric is decreasing

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, distance, metric, dice

I am facing a problem in Hausdorff and IoU, where they stop learning when reaching a specific value! While the loss and dice metric keeps changing. surface_distance also has a problem since it is always equal to "inf". I need an explanation of why this problem happens. So I could understand the solutions. Note: I am using Monai framework with builtin functions to calculate those metrics.

I am doing 3D image segmentation using U-Net and the Hausdorff is the function HausdorffDistanceMetric from Monai framework and it is explain here: https://github.com/Project-MONAI/MONAI/blob/dev/monai/metrics/hausdorff_distance.py

These are three measurements (it is the same for the following 30 epochs):

********************Testing********************
Test_loss: 0.1801
Test_Metric: 0.6199
hausdorff:  24.8
surface_distance:  inf
IoU: 0.4916495382785797
current epoch: 1 current mean dice: 0.6199
best mean dice: 0.6199 at epoch: 1

********************Testing********************
Test_loss: 0.1544
Test_Metric: 0.6456
hausdorff:  24.8
surface_distance:  inf
IoU: 0.4916495382785797
current epoch: 2 current mean dice: 0.6456
best mean dice: 0.6456 at epoch: 2

********************Testing********************
Test_loss: 0.1111
Test_Metric: 0.6889
hausdorff:  24.8
surface_distance:  inf
IoU: 0.4916495382785797
current epoch: 3 current mean dice: 0.6889
best mean dice: 0.6889 at epoch: 3

Comment: To me it looks as if you give far too little detail to make sense of this. It is not clear what exactly you are doing. Note that terms such as Hausdorff have a number of different meanings in statistics. Explaining abbreviations will also help. What are your data? What is your aim?

Comment: I am doing 3D image segmentation using U-Net and the Hausdorff is the function HausdorffDistanceMetric from Monai framework and it is explain here: https://github.com/Project-MONAI/MONAI/blob/dev/monai/metrics/hausdorff_distance.py

Comment: Please add relevant information to the question rather than in the comments.